# Why does an uninitialised DateTime struct tell me it's monday

Tags: vb.net

I have a DateTime struct I use, and sombody commented out the part where it was created (but not declared) When I was using it, myDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday returned true.

If the part where it is created is commented out, how can it tell me it's monday, instead of throwing some exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime` is a value type (a `struct`), and therefore it always has a value. It cannot be `null` like a reference type. When a variable of a value type is not assigned yet, it's initialized to some default value depending on the type. The default value for `DateTime` just happens to be a Monday in the calendar .NET uses.

Of course, calendars have changed many times in the past and applying our current calendar more than a few hundred years into the past just doesn't work, but to .NET, it's a Monday.

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime` is a struct which means that it has to have some sort of default value. The default value for `DateTime` is [`DateTime.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx), which is 1 January 0001, which was a monday.

Comment: +1, yes.  Well, that settles it.  The first day of the week has to be Monday, not Sunday.